# Ralink RT3290 bluetooth adapter is not working [full process]

Tags: bluetooth

Ralink RT3290 bluetooth adapter does not work, but wifi works perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

RT3290 buetooth adapter doesn't work for most of the user. I'm writing this process for them, how to enable RT3290 bluetooth:

(i) Open terminal. (CTRL+ALT+T)

(ii) Install RT3290 driver by typing following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blaze/rtbth-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtbth-dkms
```

(iii)Now you have installed bluetooth driver successfully. Automate the initialization process to avoid manual initialization every time when the computer switched on. For use the following commands:

(a) Open /etc/rc.local file

```
sudo pico /etc/rc.local (you can also use gedit instead of pico)
```

(b) /etc/rc.local file is now opened and looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

exit 0
```

(c) Just before "exit 0" add the command "modprobe rtbth &> /dev/null", now the file looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

modprobe rtbth &> /dev/null

exit 0
```

(d) Save the file. (Press CTRL+Z -> Press y -> Press Enter key) (Press CTRL+S and the close file, for gedit)

(e) Now give the file executable permission(for all):

```
sudo chmod 777 /etc/rc.local
```

(iv) I've tested inbuilt bluetooth available under settings, but it really can't handle both way transfer. I was unable to transfer any file from my phone to pc. So, avoid it. Open "system settings" -> "Bluetooth" -> Untick "Show Bluetooth status in the menu bar"

(v) Install Blueman(It is going to be alternative for native bluetooth software):

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

(vi) Now reboot your pc.

(vii) After rebooting, go to "Dash Board" and search "Bluetooth Adapters" and open it. (I think after installing Blueman it is already pinned in your launcher). Boom. The bluetooth is working now. You can control(switch on/switch off/transfer files) your bluetooth from the bluetooth sign available in the menu bar.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have had an Asus N56J for some years now and with this post is the first time it works (it is also the first time I try with Ubuntu 18.04). Thank you very much! The only think is that I had to manulay create `/etc/rc.local` as it was not existing in my computer. But I copied the file you have here and it worked perfectely!

Comment: Bluetooth never worked for me since ubuntu12.04, I tried everything, this is the only thing that worked. Thanks a lot.

@apalomer thanks for commenting, I would not have tried this if I did not see your comment.

Comment: The only thing I don't understand why start the module using rc.local. There is `modprobe.d` directory for that.

Comment: I have no pre-existing "etc/rc.local" file. Should I create it manually for this?