# Bluetooth adapter not found Ralink RT3290

Tags: bluetooth

I installed kubuntu 18.04 LTS on my hp pavilion g6 laptop. Everything went smoothly, except ubuntu says "no bluetooth adapter found". I am new to linux, please help

```
$lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
01:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 05)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

```
$rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

This post was marked as duplicate and I followed the previous post to thus bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/bluetooth/+bug/1189721?comments=all. The final post says that the solution can no longer be compiled

Comment: updated my post to add the output

Comment: This https://askubuntu.com/questions/453605/ might help or this https://askubuntu.com/questions/778615

Comment: Another thing I've noticed is that WiFi signal is low compared to what I used to get on windows. But I can live with that as I've not been getting disconnected nor getting slow speeds. Do you guys think moving to 18.10 will solve these driver problems?

Comment: I think https://askubuntu.com/a/1021231/ is likely to be a useful answer as it isn't that old