# Bluetooth not Working in Ubuntu 18.04.2 : hcoconfig returns nothing but bluetooth status is active

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker, xhci-hcd

I am trying to config bluetooth on my laptop.

```
 systemctl status bluetooth
```

Output : `

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-05-11 10:50:06 IST; 18min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 7084 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─7084 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 11 10:50:06 bhatia systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
May 11 10:50:06 bhatia bluetoothd[7084]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
May 11 10:50:06 bhatia systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
May 11 10:50:06 bhatia bluetoothd[7084]: Starting SDP server
May 11 10:50:06 bhatia bluetoothd[7084]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 ini`
```

and

```
sudo lsmod | grep bluetooth
```

returns :

```
bluetooth             548864  11 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
```

But

```
rfkill list
```

retuns :

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

and

```
hciconfig
```

returns nothing, 
Also

```
sudo lshw |grep  Bluetooth
```

returns :

```
description: Bluetooth
product: RT3290 Bluetooth
```

also

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
```

returns :

```
[  397.646062] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  397.646115] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  397.646119] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  397.646121] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  397.646127] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  537.743291] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  537.743294] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  537.743302] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

and

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
```

returns :

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 064e:e263 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have tried connecting a hardware bluetooth device but nothing seems to work. Please help me configure the bluetooth.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020810/ralink-rt3290-bluetooth-adapter-is-not-working-full-process still work?

Comment: Tried this link but after rebooting cannot find blueman set up new devices set no bluetooth adapter found but
 u can see in the question edit what 
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb returns
returns

Comment: Since command can detect  wifi and bluetooth adapter still blueman is saying no adapter found

Comment: Can you furnish your laptop details such as make, model? **Note:** Many laptop computers have a hardware switch or key combination to turn Bluetooth on and off. Look for a switch on your computer or a key on your keyboard. The keyboard key is often accessed with the help of the `Fn` key.