# HP4740s missing bluetooth Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bluetooth, hp

After installation everything works fine except for bluetooth.
According to Ubuntu there is no bluetooth in my PC (windows shows something different). On the HP site there is some driver (from 2013) for Linux, but its not for Debian/Ubuntu

I have limited knowledge about linux.

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
Kernel modules: rt2800pci
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0461:4e1d Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: As far as I know this BT device is poorly supported on current linux kernels.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ralink RT3290 bluetooth adapter is not working \[full process\]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020810/ralink-rt3290-bluetooth-adapter-is-not-working-full-process)